# ScalaCheck spec seeking Matcher[String] after upgrade

Tags: scala, specs2, scalacheck

After upgrading from specs 2.4.13 to 3.7.1

```
"foo" should {
  "bar" >> prop((i: Int) =>
    i % 50 must be>= 0
  )
}
```

no longer compiles. It fails with

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.specs2.specification.core.Fragment
[error]  required: org.specs2.matcher.Matcher[String]
[error]     "bar" >> prop((i: Int) =>
[error]           ^
```

Changing it to

```
  "foo" >> {
    "bar" >> prop((i: Int) =>
      i % 50 must be>= 0
    )
  }
```

will allow it to compile and pass.

Has the behaviour of `should` been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get such error in `3.8.8`. However this might be the result of `should` being used for a block of examples and `should` as a matcher construct (`a should be_>=(0)`).

You can remove the latter usage by mixing-in `org.specs2.matcher.NoShouldExpectations`